# Can't input 2d array through vector. Error : no match for operator>>

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int check(vector<int>,int );
int i,j;
  int main()
 {
int T,N,M,E,Sr,Sc,Tr,Tc;
int & en = E;
// &en = &E;
std:: vector<int>  a[100][100];
cin>>T;
for(int x=1;x<T;x++)
{
    cin>>N>>M>>E>>Sr>>Sc>>Tr>>Tc;
    //cin.ignore();
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<M;j++)

        {cin>>a[i][j];}  //contains error 

    }
```

I was solving a Google Kickstart problem ( CaveEscape) until I found this error while trying to get array input.
Also please do tell if my array initialization is wrong.

Comment: What is this supposed to do `{cin>>a[i][j];}`?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Accept input into an `int`, presumably?

Comment: Probably `std:: vector<int>  a[100][100]` -> `int a[100][100]`;?

Comment: what value did you input for T N  M

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. For the next question, make it a minimal and compilable example. Furthermore, please indent the code properly

Answer (score 1):

Your vector declaration is suspect.

It looks like you started off with a 2D array of `int`s:

```
int a[100][100];
```

which would have been fine.

Then you turned it into a vector, but you made it a 2D array of vectors!

You can't read from a stream directly into a vector (one of your array elements) because you didn't tell the computer how you would like it to do that (whereas reading into an `int` is something it already knows how to do).

Since actual 2D vectors are silly and having a 2D facade over a 1D vector seems too complex for this simple task, I'm going to recommend you flip back to a bog-standard array.

However, if you're dead set on a vector, it'd look something like this:

```
std::vector<int> a(100*100);
// i×j is a[i + j*100]
```

Or:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> a(100, std::vector<int>(100));
// i×j is a[i][j]
// ew though! poor cache locality, no contiguity, and lots of dynamic allocations
```

*(Disclaimer: I may have flipped the rows and columns between those last examples, and don't have the brain capacity or the inclination to work it out, because it doesn't matter, because you shouldn't take this approach :P)*

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of 2D vector is wrong. 2D vectors can be implemented as vector of vector such as:

```
std::vector<std::vector <int> >  a;
```

Here is sample code to take input from the user using this format:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int check(vector<int>, int);
int i, j;

int main()
{
    int T, N, M, E, Sr, Sc, Tr, Tc;
    int & en = E;
    // &en = &E;
    std::vector<std::vector <int> >  a;
    cin >> T;
    for (int x = 1; x < T; x++)
    {
        cin >> N >> M >> E >> Sr >> Sc >> Tr >> Tc;
        //cin.ignore();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            vector<int> b;
            for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            {

                int temp;
                cin >> temp;
                b.push_back(temp);
            }
            a.push_back(b);
        }
    }
}
```